# Comparing dates updated_at to current month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to display in my table in views rows only where date in update_at include current month. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below should work

```
@some_variable = YourModel.where('extract(month from updated_at) = ?', Date.today.month)
```